# XeLaTeX misplaces ActualText box

Tags: xetex, boxes, copy-paste, accsupp

The following MWE uses accessibility features of PDF provided by the package `accsupp` to replace the content of the selection corresponding to `BBB` with `ZZZ` in the string `AAABBBCCC`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\begin{document}
AAA\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=ZZZ}BBB\EndAccSupp{}CCC
\end{document}
```

If it is compiled with `pdflatex` everything works fine.

Compilation with `xelatex` results in a gross misplacement of the box corresponding to `ZZZ`, as can be seen in the following picture produced using `evince` (other viewers show the same issue).

[image: The result]

Why is this happening? Can the problem be fixed?

(I cannot give up `xelatex` in favour of `pdflatex`.)

---

## Further analysis

I decompressed the PDFs using `qpdf` and examined the outputs.
The crucial differences are all in a single stream (i.e. replacing the `xelatex` one by the one produced with `pdflatex` and adjusting the fonts everything works as expected).

XeLaTeX outputs

```pdf
stream
q 1 0 0 1 72 769.89 cm
BT
/F1 9.963 Tf 76.71 -62.76 Td[(AAA)]TJ
ET
q 1 0 0 1 99.13 -62.76 cm
/Span<</ActualText(ZZZ)>>BDC
Q
BT
/F1 9.963 Tf 99.13 -62.76 Td[(BBB)]TJ
ET
q 1 0 0 1 120.3 -62.76 cm
EMC
Q
BT
/F1 9.963 Tf 120.3 -62.76 Td[(CCC)]TJ 110.83 -567.88 Td[(1)]TJ
ET
Q
endstream
```

while PDFLaTeX does

```pdf
stream
BT
/F8 9.9626 Tf 148.712 707.125 Td [(AAA)]TJ
ET
/Span<</ActualText(ZZZ)>>BDC
BT
/F8 9.9626 Tf 171.128 707.125 Td [(BBB)]TJ
ET
EMC
BT
/F8 9.9626 Tf 192.299 707.125 Td [(CCC)]TJ 110.834 -567.87 Td [(1)]TJ
ET
endstream
```

It seems that the only difference is that XeLaTeX prefers jumping back and forth with coordinate transformations. Maybe this raw code can help someone shed some light on the behaviour.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how that works or how I can reproduce this error? I just see AAABBBCCC in two different viewers but I am not that familiar with `accsupp`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi The problem is not visual but functional. Try selecting the text (dragging from `A` to `C`): the highlighted area corresponding to `BBB` is offset, like in the picture. This means that if one tries to select `BBB` nothing happens because the actual box is not where `BBB` appears. `accsupp` replaces the content of text selection: if you copy `AAABBBCCC` you will paste `AAAZZZCCC`.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks for the description! Like that I could test it. I use Adobe Reader 11.0.1 and it works. In Sumatra, the replacement does not work, but the selection works.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi it does? It doesn't work for me with xetex in cygwin texlive 2015

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I checked again. TeXStudio, MikTeX2.9, Win7. Compiled once with XeLaTeX, opend in Adobe Reader 11.0.1, selected and copied back in TeXstudio. AAAZZZCCC (I will rebuild my XeLaTeX now... keep your fingers crossed that I don't destroy my setup!)

Comment: Still working, everything updated. Compiled from command line. Opened directly in Adobe.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi wait for Heiko to pass by:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question, which includes a thorough analyis!

I did not find any official documentation of XeTeX for the equivalent for pdfTeX's `\pdfliteral direct`. The manual of `dvipdfm`, some predecessor of XeTeX describes `\special{pdf:content ...}`. Nothing in `xetex-reference.pdf` or `XeTeX-notes.pdf`.

In file `pgfsys-dvipdfm.def` the following "ugly hack" can be found:

```
\def\pgfsys@invoke#1{\special{pdf: content Q #1 q}} % ugly, but necessary...
```

`dvipdfmx` seems to support a new keyword `code`, `pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def` contains:

```
% `pdf:code' is an abbreviation of `pdf:literal direct', the idea of which
% came from pdfTeX's primitive \pdfliteral direct.
\def\pgfsys@invoke#1{\special{pdf:code #1}}
```

This seems also be supported in XeTeX.

Thus the following patch should fix the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\makeatletter
\def\ACCSUPP@bdc{%
  \special{pdf:code \ACCSUPP@span BDC}%
}
\def\ACCSUPP@emc{%
  \special{pdf:code EMC}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
AAA\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=ZZZ}BBB\EndAccSupp{}CCC
\end{document}
```

The PDF page stream (reformatted):

```pdf
stream
q
  1 0 0 1 72 769.89 cm
  BT
    /F1 9.963 Tf
    76.71 -62.76 Td
    [(AAA)]TJ
  ET
  /Span<</ActualText(ZZZ)>>BDC
  BT
    /F1 9.963 Tf
    99.13 -62.76 Td
    [(BBB)]TJ
  ET
  EMC
  BT
    /F1 9.963 Tf
    120.3 -62.76 Td
    [(CCC)]TJ
    110.83 -567.88 Td
    [(1)]TJ
  ET
Q
endstream
```

Comment: +1 I had the feeling that you'd be the one to answer this:-)

Comment: There is no accsup in texlive and when I wanted to download it from CTAN I got only the .dtx file and no .ins file. How can I install it on my system?

Comment: @yannis The package is called `accsupp` with two `p`. The TeX Live package has the same name and can be installed.