# Fontspec:addfontfeature LetterSpace operation

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I need to use letter-spacing on words inside paragraphs. I made some experiments with fontspec and the LetterSpace feature.

While the rendering seems to be correct, I observed that on some configuration, space characters are inserted between the word letters. (Which is a problem, since it make those words impossible to look for).

- The problem seems to occur when there is spaced and non spaced text on the same line.
- I am not sure of what is wrong in my code and if there is a way to control this behaviour.

My tex file :

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeMono}
\begin{document}
    This is a text \\
    {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}This is a short spaced text}\\
    {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}This is a spaced text} This is not spaced text \\
    {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}This is a another, longer than the previous one, spaced text} \\
    This is normal text
\end{document}
```

Pdf rendering :

[image: This is the rendered PDF]

Text content :

[image: This is the text content]

Comment: PDF viewers have heuristics to add spaces when copying text which are generally unreliable when letter spacing is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use accsupp to add an /Actualtext (such a text should be short, so if needed do it word by word):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeMono}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\begin{document}

    This is a text \\
    {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}%
     \BeginAccSupp {method=plain,ActualText=This is a short spaced text}%
      This is a short spaced text\EndAccSupp{}} This is a text
    \\
    {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}This is a spaced text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I has some issues using it with xetex, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262492/xelatex-misplaces-actualtext-box) helped me figure it out.